# VBA script causing excel to stop responding

Tags: vba, excel, attachmate-extra

I have the following vba code running from excel which interacts with the an additional program perfectly.

```
' Global variable declarations
Public g_HostSettleTime%
Public g_szPassword$
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub PlanGroups()


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get the main system object
    Dim Sessions As Object
    Dim System As Object

    If MsgBox("Is your mainframe is on screen TOP MNU? Do you have access to PCMB03?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

Exit Sub
End If



    Set System = GetObject("", "EXTRA.System")
        If System Is Nothing Then
            Set System = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
    If (System Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the EXTRA System object.  Stopping macro playback."
        Stop
    End If
        End If
    Set System = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")   ' Gets the system object
    If (System Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the EXTRA System object.  Stopping macro playback."
        Stop
    End If

    Set Sessions = System.Sessions.Open("C:\Program Files (x86)\E!PC\Sessions\Mainfrme.edp")
        If Sessions Is Nothing Then
            Set Sessions = System.Sessions.Open("C:\Program Files (x86)\E!PC\Sessions\Mainframe.edp")
            If MySession Is Nothing Then
                Response = MsgBox("Could not create the EXTRA Session object", vbCritical, "EXTRA Session")
                End
            End If
        End If


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Set the default wait timeout value
    g_HostSettleTime = 30       ' milliseconds

    OldSystemTimeout& = System.TimeoutValue
    If (g_HostSettleTime > OldSystemTimeout) Then
        System.TimeoutValue = g_HostSettleTime
    End If

' Get the necessary Session Object
    Dim Sess0 As Object
    Set Sess0 = System.ActiveSession
    If (Sess0 Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the Session object.  Stopping macro playback."
        Stop
    End If
    If Not Sess0.Visible Then Sess0.Visible = True


 'paste macro below
Worksheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Activate

If Application.CountA(Range("A9")) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "PLEASE ENTER VALID DATA STARTING FROM ROW 9!"
            Set System = Nothing
Set Sessions = Nothing
Set Sess0 = Nothing

            Exit Sub

End If



Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(1, 1).Value = Sess0.Screen.GetString(2, 3, 7)

If Not Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(1, 1) = ("TOP MNU") Then
    MsgBox "You are not in TOP MNU...Liar."
    Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(1, 1).Clear
    Set System = Nothing
Set Sessions = Nothing
Set Sess0 = Nothing

    Exit Sub
    End If
Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(1, 1).Clear



If IsEmpty(Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(8, 4).Value) Then
    MsgBox "Enter a valid Mainframe ID."
Set System = Nothing
Set Sessions = Nothing
Set Sess0 = Nothing

    Exit Sub
    End If


Sess0.Screen.MoveTo 24, 72
Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("PCMB03<PF2>")
  Do While Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus <> 0
    DoEvents
    Loop



    Dim rngFoundG As Range

    With Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS")
        Set rngFoundG = .Columns("A:A").Find("", After:=.Range("A8"), _
            SearchDirection:=xlDown)

    End With




Dim PlanGroup As String
Dim MainFrameID As String
MainFrameID = Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(8, 4).Value
Sleep (50)
Sess0.Screen.MoveTo 6, 25
Sess0.Screen.SendKeys (MainFrameID & "<ENTER>")
Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(8, 5).Value = Sess0.Screen.GetString(6, 38, 30)


LastCell = rngFoundG.Row - 1

For i = 9 To LastCell
Sleep (50)
PlanGroup = Format(Cells(i, "A").Value, "0000")
Sess0.Screen.MoveTo 10, 38
    Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("<EraseEOF>" & PlanGroup & "<Enter>")
  Do While Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus <> 0
    DoEvents
    Loop
    Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("<PF12>")
  Do While Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus <> 0
    DoEvents
    Loop
    Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sess0.Screen.GetString(23, 2, 17)
       If Not Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(i, 2).Value = "UPDATE SUCCESSFUL" Then
       Sheets("ADD PLANNING GROUPS").Cells(i, 2).Value = "Error"
   End If
Next
Set System = Nothing
Set Sessions = Nothing
Set Sess0 = Nothing
Set rngFoundG = Nothing


    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

However, the issue after one run through, which is flawless, after approximately 10-15 seconds, excel freezes and needs to be manually closed down. Is there any reason for this? From my research I have set my variables and objects to nothing but this still does not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint in one of the `Do While` loops and ensured that `Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus` will actually change to something else than `0`? Otherwise (when `Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus` stays at `0`) this might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Do you mean 10-15 seconds after the code has _finished_ ? If so then you've probably not closed or released a COM object properly or something. If it's _while_ the code is running then press Ctrl+Break to pause execution and see what line is causing the issue.

Comment: i's a bit strange seeing those two  `do while` inside a `for` loop. I don't see what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @bassfader The macro does reach the end, so I am not too sure if it gets stuck in the loop. I have however taken your suggestion onboard and adapted it to `Do Until Sess0.Screen.OIA.Xstatus = 0
    DoEvents
    Loop`, which does the same thing but fixes the issue that may arise as you said. However this does not fix the original problem of the freezing.

Comment: @MacroMan It is not always 10-15 seconds, my apologies. Sometimes it can be when I switch straight over to the mainframe and start manually entering data, excel will freeze. It is never during the code running, always at least 10 seconds once it finishes

Comment: Are you working with a file on a network drive?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier The point of the `do while`, is to wait for the mainframe to to finish all of its processes before continuing. Waiting for the `sess0.screen.OIA.Xstatus ` to be 0, meaning all processes are done before carrying on. I did try using the `application.wait ` method and  `wait.host.quiet `, however these froze the code whilst running. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MacroMan Nope, the plan was to put it on a network drive, however right now it is not.

Comment: @Vik just to clarify, if the code finished then it's nothing to do with the code _per se_ - VBA doesn't cope well with processes or threading, and so it could be a message being sent by the code, but received after the code has finished causing some kind of deadlock or something. All hypothetical at this point but I don't think there is anything you can do in  the code other than add something at the end to act as a listener for anything being returned or something...

Comment: @MacroMan That is unfortunate, well thank you for your help. I will still persist in trying to find a solution, if I do, I will post it here. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Vik does the `system` object not have a `.Quit()` method or similar? Using `Set system = Nothing` is simply releasing the object from memory, it's not actually terminating the process (if you look at task manager you will see what I mean)

Comment: @MacroMan it does have a quit option, however it is not something I want to do, since the plan is to continue using the system